# .Net Core View: the name "Layout" does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to build a .net core mvc project.

When I add a view in this way:
Right click folder -> Add View -> Add
[image]

[image]

Then `the name "Layout" does not exist in the current context`
[image]

Restart vs or build the project this error still exist.

However, If I add view in this way:

Right click folder -> Add New Items -> MVC View Page
[image]

the Layout can be recognized.

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vs 2017 you have to add this code in new  csproj which you created.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Because When you create a new Web application, this gets set to the "Web" SDK:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">...</Project>
```

so the Web SDK imports additional tasks to allow design-time processing of Web resources, such as Razor views. Change the SDK in your plugin library to Web.
after you build error should be vanished.